# How to toggle Action Bar while touching the map like Uber

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have implemented a map that behaves like Uber app i.e pin in center and map drags under the pin and the pin gets the location from map. But I am not able to implement the touch event for toggling the action bar just exactly Uber do. Please help me to implement that feature. First I have used support map fragment but to set touch events a view was required so later on I used MapView.Below is my code:

```
package com.example.myfastapp;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class mapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    MapView mapView;
    //private View touch;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng center;
    private LatLng currentpoint;

    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    protected Context context;
    SupportMapFragment mf;
    View v;
    private static final CharSequence[] MAP_TYPE_ITEMS = { "Road Map",
            "Satellite", "Terrain" };

    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private TextView markerText, Address;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

    private GPSTracker gps;

    // Milliseconds per second
    public static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    // The update interval
    public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;

    // A fast interval ceiling
    public static final int FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS = 1;

    // Update interval in milliseconds
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // A fast ceiling of update intervals, used when the app is visible
    public static final long FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS;

    public mapFragment(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, container, false);



//      v.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        mapView = (MapView)v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





        ImageButton mapType = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.mapType);
        mapType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMapTypeSelectorDialog();

            }
        });

        ImageButton myLocationCustomButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.myLocationCustom);
        myLocationCustomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
                gps.canGetLocation();
                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                currentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentpoint, 18);
                map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            }
        });



        markerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        Address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.adressText);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
                                                    // not available
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                    getActivity(), requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

            /*
             * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
             * callbacks.
             */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        return v;

    }





    public void toggleActionBar() 
    {
        ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();

        if (ab != null) 
        {
            if (ab.isShowing()) 
            {
                ab.hide();
            } 
            else 
            {
                if(!ab.isShowing())
            {
                ab.show();
            }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupMap() {
        try {
            /*map = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();*/




            map = mapView.getMap();



            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
            map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                            new LocationListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                    markerText.setText("Location received: "
                                            + location.toString());

                                }
                            });

            Log.e("Reached", "here");
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {

                    if (status.isSuccess()) {

                        Log.e("Result", "success");

                    } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                        // Google provides a way to fix the issue
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 100);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
            gps.canGetLocation();
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            currentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(currentpoint).zoom(16f).tilt(30).bearing(90).build();

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            map.clear();

            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //toggleActionBar();
                    center = map.getCameraPosition().target;

                    markerText.setText(" Set your Location ");
                    map.clear();
                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try 
                    {
                        new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });




            markerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude,
                                center.longitude);

                        Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng1)
                                .title(" Set your Location ")
                                .snippet("")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.my_location)));
                        m.setDraggable(true);

                        markerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        setupMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // boolean duplicateResponse;
        double x, y;
        StringBuilder str;

        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Address.setText(" Getting location ");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + " ");
                    str.append(city + " " + region_code + " ");
                    str.append(zipcode + " ");

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", "
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    /*
     * public void addMarker(double lati, double longi) {
     * 
     * LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lati, longi);
     * 
     * MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions(); mo.position(latlng);
     * mo.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_location));
     * mo.title("My Location:"+ latlng); map.addMarker(mo);
     * 
     * //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,
     * 15));//previous code CameraPosition cameraPosition = new
     * CameraPosition.Builder() .target(latlng) .zoom(11.0f) .bearing(90) //
     * Orientation of the camera to east .tilt(30) // Tilt of the camera to 30
     * degrees .build();
     * map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
     * map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     * map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
     * map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
     * //map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); }
     */

    public void showMapTypeSelectorDialog() {
        // Prepare the dialog by setting up a Builder.
        final String fDialogTitle = "Select Map Type";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(fDialogTitle);
        // Find the current map type to pre-check the item representing the
        // current state.
        int checkItem = map.getMapType() - 1;
        System.out.print(checkItem);
        // Add an OnClickListener to the dialog, so that the selection will be
        // handled.
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(MAP_TYPE_ITEMS, checkItem,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
                    {
                        // Locally create a finalised object.
                        // Perform an action depending on which item was
                        // selected.
                        switch (item) 
                        {
                        case 1:
                            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                            break;
                        default:
                            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        // Build the dialog and show it.
        AlertDialog fMapTypeDialog = builder.create();
        fMapTypeDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        fMapTypeDialog.show();
    }

     @Override
     public void onResume() 
     {

         super.onResume();

         mapView.onResume();
         mapView.getMap();


     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() 
     {
         super.onPause();
         mapView.onPause();

     }


     @Override
     public void onLowMemory() 
     {
         super.onLowMemory();
         mapView.onLowMemory();
     }

}
```

Comment: can you explain what Uber does that you were not able to do ? possibly post a screenshot ? I can help you better if I know exactly what you want.

Comment: When we click on the map to move the pin over map, Toolbar that we have manually set, will get hidden. When we take our hand from screen that actionbar wil return. This is what he actually meant, Could you please help

Comment: have you got any solution for that

Comment: i need same like your question

Comment: @IndranilDutta did you get any solution?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar no I didn't find any solution. But custom action bar  can be a solution. Custom action bar means designing like action bar in activity and the activity theme will be no action bar.

Comment: @IndranilDutta I am using toolbar. I can hide it. And i need hide some other views also. Problem is how to find when user is touching and relieving the map ?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar in your activity you can place your header and the map can contain in a fragment. so through interface you can handle the hiding of your header or topbar. on the map you can have a listener which will have motion event. on action down you can hide the topbar.

Answer (score 3):

The `onCameraChangeListener` is deprecated, but good news is that google has released 3 new listeners.

See: [GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)

> This interface was deprecated.
>
> Replaced by `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener`, `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener` and `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`. The order in which the deprecated `onCameraChange` method will be called in relation to the methods in the new camera change listeners is undefined.

I have used these listeners and now i am able get the hold and release event on map.

Answer (score 0):

I  believe you should add an [onMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener) to your map object and do your code inside.

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_bcg"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_white_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="Desc"/>
```

> This is methods for show and hide views
>    private void hideViews() {
>           mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mFabButton.getLayoutParams();
    int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
    mFabButton.animate().translationY(mFabButton.getHeight()+fabBottomMargin).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}

private void showViews() {
    mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    mFabButton.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}
```